# Local RTCMediaStream is not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, webrtc, iphone-6, kurento

I am creating local video stream using below code once the “call” is placed. The local media stream of my iPhone 6 is not getting generated however remote media stream is working perfectly on my phone. Does anyone has any idea why I am not able to get the local media stream of iPhone?

I am using Kurento Media Server with node.js.

```
- (RTCMediaStream *)createLocalMediaStream {

    RTCMediaConstraints *constraints = [self defaultPeerConnectionConstraints];
    self.peerConnection = [self.peerConnectionFactory peerConnectionWithICEServers:server
                                                 constraints:constraints
                                                    delegate:self];
    RTCMediaStream *localStream = [self createLocalMediaStream];
    [self.peerConnection addStream:localStream];
    [_peerConnection createOfferWithDelegate:self constraints:[self defaultOfferConstraints]];

    RTCMediaStream* localStream = [self.peerConnectionFactory mediaStreamWithLabel:@"ARDAMS"];
    RTCVideoTrack* localVideoTrack = nil;

#if !TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR && TARGET_OS_IPHONE
    NSString *cameraID = nil;
    for (AVCaptureDevice *captureDevice in
         [AVCaptureDevice devicesWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo]) {
        if (captureDevice.position == AVCaptureDevicePositionFront) {
            cameraID = [captureDevice localizedName];
            break;
        }
    }
    NSAssert(cameraID, @"Unable to get the front camera id");

    RTCVideoCapturer *capturer = [RTCVideoCapturer capturerWithDeviceName:cameraID];
    RTCMediaConstraints* constraints = [self defaultMediaStreamConstraints];
    RTCVideoSource *videoSource = [self.peerConnectionFactory videoSourceWithCapturer:capturer constraints:constraints];

    localVideoTrack =
    [self.peerConnectionFactory videoTrackWithID:@"ARDAMSv0" source:videoSource];
    if (localVideoTrack) {
        [localStream addVideoTrack:localVideoTrack];
    }
    [self.delegate connectionManager:self didReceiveLocalVideoTrack:localVideoTrack];
#endif
    [localStream addAudioTrack:[self.peerConnectionFactory audioTrackWithID:@"ARDAMSa0"]];
    return localStream;
}

- (RTCMediaConstraints *)defaultPeerConnectionConstraints {
    NSArray *optionalConstraints = @[
                                     [[RTCPair alloc] initWithKey:@"DtlsSrtpKeyAgreement" value:@"true"]
                                     ];
    RTCMediaConstraints* constraints =
    [[RTCMediaConstraints alloc] initWithMandatoryConstraints:nil optionalConstraints:optionalConstraints];
    return constraints;
}

- (RTCMediaConstraints *)defaultOfferConstraints {
    NSArray *mandatoryConstraints = @[
                                      [[RTCPair alloc] initWithKey:@"OfferToReceiveAudio" value:@"true"],
                                      [[RTCPair alloc] initWithKey:@"OfferToReceiveVideo" value:@"true"]
                                      ];
    RTCMediaConstraints* constraints = [[RTCMediaConstraints alloc] initWithMandatoryConstraints:mandatoryConstraints optionalConstraints:nil];
    return constraints;
}

- (RTCMediaConstraints *)defaultMediaStreamConstraints {    
    NSArray *mandatoryConstraints = @[
                                      [[RTCPair alloc] initWithKey:@"maxWidth" value:@"640"],
                                      [[RTCPair alloc] initWithKey:@"minWidth" value:@"640"],
                                      [[RTCPair alloc] initWithKey:@"maxHeight" value:@"480"],
                                      [[RTCPair alloc] initWithKey:@"minHeight" value:@"480"],
                                      [[RTCPair alloc] initWithKey:@"maxFrameRate" value:@"30"],
                                      [[RTCPair alloc] initWithKey:@"minFrameRate" value:@"5"],
                                      [[RTCPair alloc] initWithKey:@"googLeakyBucket" value:@"true"]
                                      ];

    RTCMediaConstraints *constrains = [[RTCMediaConstraints alloc] initWithMandatoryConstraints:mandatoryConstraints optionalConstraints:nil];
    return constrains;
}
```

Comment: What revision of Webrtc are you using?

Comment: @GuyS - thanks for replying, I was creating a local stream using background thread. I moved it to main thread and it worked.

Comment: @Ankur was this the issue with your other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30391057/webrtc-get-local-media-stream-crash-on-iphone)? Is it a duplicate?

Comment: @igracia: both the questions had different issues with same functionality... :)

Comment: @Ankur can you point me some direction to follow the implementation of Kurento, since I have implemented native version of WebRTC on iOS?

Comment: Try to use empty array @[] instead of nil for optional constrains